# How to enlarge font of street names while printing in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap, google-maps, printing, qgis-openlayers-plugin

I have to print some Municipality shots and I use OpenStreetMaps or Google Maps but when I print the streets names are too little and is is not possible to read them. On screen names are perfectly legible and the size is right.
How can I solve?

I use OpenLayerPlugin v1.4.1

Comment: don't use the OpenLayerPlugin use QuickMaps instead

Comment: a workaround might be to download the data from osm and style it according to your needs

Comment: @iant QuickMapServices give an error when I try to install it: puglin corrupted

Comment: please ask a new question, including details of your OS, version of QGIS and any relevant error message